# Computer referring to Anaconda as Python

Tags: python, anaconda

Image in link shows it the best. As you can see I'm in the anaconda navigator but my computer has changed the icon at the bottom to python and when I right click my computer is calling the anaconda navigator python? I'm so confused. [SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qH6Th.png)

Comment: What is the problem you're facing?

Comment: The Anaconda Navigator is an application written in Python, so the process is "Python.exe".  That's all the icon is showing you.  Pay no attention to the man behind the curtain.